# $resource PUT operation not extracting id

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I can't seem to get an "id" to come through to the `$resource` function from the controller. Here is the offending code...

Controller:

```
$scope.update_user_extra = function () {
    UserExtraResource.update($scope.user_extra_details, function (data) {
        $scope.user_extra_details = data;
        $scope.user_extra_details = {mobile:data.mobile,
                                     landline:data.landline,
                                     position:data.position, 
                                     notes:data.notes, 
                                     language:data.language};
    });
};
```

Resource:

```
module.exports = function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/user_extra/:id/', { id: '@_id' }, {      
        details: {method: 'GET', url: '/api/user_extra/details'},
        update: {method: 'PUT'}
    });
};
```

The GET works fine but the custom PUT returns:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user_extra/ 404 (Not Found)

hardcoding the id like:

```
return $resource('/api/user_extra/1/', { id: '@_id' }, {
```

works fine. Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Are you sure the `$scope.user_extra_details` object has an `_id` property?

Comment: hmm ... changing this line to: ```return $resource('/api/user_extra/1/', { id: '@id' }, {  ``` seems to have done it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> hmm ... changing this line to:
>
> ```
> return $resource('/api/user_extra/:id/', { id: ̶'̶@̶_̶i̶d̶'̶ '@id' }, {
> ```
>
> seems to have done it. Thank you very much!

If the default parameter value is prefixed with @, then the value for that parameter will be **extracted from the corresponding property on the data object**. For example, if the `defaultParam` object is `{someParam: '@someProp'}` then the value of `someParam` will be `data.someProp`.

In the above question, the PUT operation was trying to extract the property `_id` of the data object when the name of the property was actually `id`.

For more information, see [AngularJS $resource API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).